# Wordpress add page/post url/path on Facebook/Twitter share

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add post/page url on Facebook/Twitter share but due to my low knowledge of knowledge in wordpresss i don't know how to do that.

I add `echo get_permalink()` but that doesn't work.

Code located on function.php

```
$string .= '<li class="facebook" id="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=echo get_permalink()">Facebook</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing your php..

change this

```
$string .= '<li class="facebook" id="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u= <?php echo get_permalink() ; ?> ">Facebook</a></li>';
```

to this

```
$string .= '<li class="facebook" id="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.get_post_permalink().'">Facebook</a></li>';
```

or for readability

```
$string.= '<li class="facebook" id="facebook">';
$string.= '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=';
$string.= get_post_permalink();
$string.= '">Facebook</a></li>';
```

have a look into [php string concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)